# Expand submenu list OL if any of the its list li has active class

Tags: javascript, css

I have tree structure based menu and by default sub list as closed, I want to show only that block of list which li  anchor `a` has `active` class.

I tried few thing but i doing something wrong in targeting the right element.

Let us say i want to keep About section open as it has sub menu's and one of its elemnts has `active` class 
`<li><a href="#" class='active'>Mission</a></li>`

```
<h1>Click on Contact</h1>
<div class="page-left-bar">
  <ol id='expList'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu long name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About </a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#" class='active'>Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/k2jqqbbk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by placing the code in document.ready... kindly check the updated jsfiddle...

**HTML**

```
<h1>Click on Contact</h1>
<div class="page-left-bar">
  <ol id='expList'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu long name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About </a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#" class='active'>Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){




       $("#expList > li").click(function () {
            $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
        });


$('#expList > li').children().has('.active').css('display', 'block');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I banged my head with `closest`, `parent` etc properties.. never occurred to me using `children ` this way.. closest did work but it opened wrong list at time

Comment: happy i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this in jQuery:

```
$('.active').closest('ol').css('display', 'block');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2jqqbbk/3/

Comment: @Hohsen, I had tried `closest`  it was not getting be right result at time, It was keeping more than one sub list open at time. so far  `$('#expList > li').children().has('.active').css('display', 'block');` works without any issue. It may be working correctly in this example but failed when i tried it with actual menu which is quite long with around 14 parent & around 10 sub list etc..